# how to create calculated pivot in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

**Scenario**

Company XYZ sells products. Company measures their performance by checking how long does it take to complete the entire order. Each order goes through multiple status (Example : Open, Pending, Close)

They count days for each status to know how many days an order was on a particular status. the days are calculated in two different ways, Working Days and Calendar Days

Please refer to the below table:

[image]

**Question**

How to turn this table into a pivot table shown in below picture? also how to add to additional columns which is total of each Working and business day status.

Desired Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        OrderID,
        OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
        DayCount
    FROM CalendarTable     
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    OrderID,
    CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN 'TotalWorking' ELSE 'TotalCalendar' END,
    DayCount
    FROM CalendarTable
) AS t
PIVOT
(
   MAX(DayCount)
   For StatusType IN(OpenWorking,
                     OpenCalendar,
                     CloseWorking,
                     CloseCalendar,
                     PendingWorking,
                     PendingCalendar,
                     TotalWorking,
                     TotalCalendar)
) AS p;
```

This will give you:

[image]

---

If you don't want to write down all the statuses manually, then you can do ti dynamically:

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(StatusType)
                       FROM 
                       (
                            SELECT 
                              OrderID,
                              OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
                              DayCount
                            FROM CalendarTable     
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT 
                              OrderID,
                              CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN 'TotalWorking' ELSE 'TotalCalendar' END,
                              DayCount
                            FROM CalendarTable
                        ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');


SELECT @query = 'SELECT *
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                      OrderID,
                      OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
                      DayCount
                    FROM CalendarTable     
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                      OrderID,
                      CASE WHEN CountType = ''Working'' THEN ''TotalWorking'' ELSE ''TotalCalendar'' END,
                      DayCount
                    FROM CalendarTable
                ) AS t
                PIVOT
                (
                   MAX(DayCount)
                   For StatusType IN(' + @cols + ')' +
                  ') p';

execute(@query);
```

---

**Update:**

For column names you can create a new variable `@colnames` and populate it with the names you want. For the Totals, you can add a `WHERE` clause to get the total for statuses active and pending only. So your query will be like this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @colnames AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(StatusType)
                       FROM 
                       (
                            SELECT 
                              OrderID,
                              OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
                              DayCount
                            FROM CalendarTable     
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT 
                              OrderID,
                              CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN 'TotalWorking' ELSE 'TotalCalendar' END,
                              DayCount
                            FROM CalendarTable
                            WHERE OrderStatus IN('Active', 'Pending')
                        ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');


SELECT @colnames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(StatusType) + ' AS ' + QUOTENAME(StatusTypeName)
                       FROM 
                       (
                           SELECT 
                                OrderID,
                                OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
                                DayCount,
                                OrderStatus + CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN  'WorkDays' ELSE 'CalDays' END AS StatusTypeName
                            FROM CalendarTable     
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT 
                              OrderID,
                              CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN 'TotalWorking' ELSE 'TotalCalendar' END,
                              DayCount,
                              CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN 'TotalWorking' ELSE 'TotalCalendar' END
                            FROM CalendarTable
                            WHERE OrderStatus IN('Active', 'Pending')
                        ) AS t
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query = 'SELECT OrderID , ' + @colnames + '
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT 
                      OrderID,
                      OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
                      DayCount
                    FROM CalendarTable     
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT 
                      OrderID,
                      CASE WHEN CountType = ''Working'' THEN ''TotalWorking'' ELSE ''TotalCalendar'' END,
                      DayCount
                    FROM CalendarTable
                    WHERE OrderStatus IN(''Active'', ''Pending'')
                ) AS t
                PIVOT
                (
                   SUM(DayCount)
                   For StatusType IN(' + @cols + ')' +
                  ') p';

execute(@query);
```

This will give you:

[image]

---

### Update

If you want to add a where clause to the manual pivot query, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        OrderID,
        OrderStatus + CountType AS StatusType,
        DayCount
    FROM CalendarTable     
    WHERE ...
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    OrderID,
    CASE WHEN CountType = 'Working' THEN 'TotalWorking' ELSE 'TotalCalendar' END,
    DayCount
    FROM CalendarTable
    WHERE ...
) AS t
PIVOT
(
   MAX(DayCount)
   For StatusType IN(OpenWorking,
                     OpenCalendar,
                     CloseWorking,
                     CloseCalendar,
                     PendingWorking,
                     PendingCalendar,
                     TotalWorking,
                     TotalCalendar)
) AS p;
```

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud, How can get extra two columns as well ? for the total counts of working and business days for all the status. as I mentioned in the question ?

Comment: @Lokapedia - Sorry, my fault, I forget it. I updated my answer,  please find my updated queries.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I will update you soon on the results :) thanks alot

Comment: I tested the manaul script and it is giving me the desired result. But Can I ask you for 2 more things as below ? (1) How to change the column names? (2) The last two columns of total working days and total calendar days.. I only want total of the 'Active' and 'Pending' Status day counts.. not any other status

Comment: Thank mate.. the dynamic query is working fine but Where can I add the WHERE clause in the original manual pivot table script to get total of only two statuses?

Comment: I added the Where statement just before AS t .. but it says incorrect syntax. ( I am referring to your very first script in this answer) where the columns are declared manually.